# Looking for a responsive design solution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a twitter bootstrap website and can't figure out how to make the design work without breaking.  When the site is wider than about 770px it works well but the two divs on either side of the carousel are positioned relative in order to move them down for aesthetic effect(how the client wants it).  the problem is that once the site width gets to about 770px, the right side div starts to collide with one below, and then at about 735 it really breaks.  I tried to use a media query(which I'm not very experienced using media queries) to correct the issue, but it seems to cause other issues(I can't the css to all stay consistent) and I'm wondering if anyone can think of a better solution before sinking hours into wrangling with the css.

You can see it here:

http://www.mcquistonator.com/pdxmobilebootstrap/index.html

Comment: you can isolate the CSS issue by assigning a specific class name to the carousel object. I'll work on a full answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so change your "top: ...;" rules for each of the two side boxes to "margin-top: ...;" and I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Skrivener is absolutely right about the floating divs.

```
.valuelist {
  background-color: #787878;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

and

```
.affordable {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 120px;
  background: #0e2b6f url('../img/peel.png') no-repeat fixed left top;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120%;
}
```

**However, there's another issue to note:**

This img tag is going to cause you headaches:

```
/bootstrap.css:101
img {
  width: auto 9; /* the 9 is an error */
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

because it's sizing your logo and your carousel images in tandem. If you want to address the issue of your carousel images not spanning 100% (view the site above 1330px or at 767px to see the carousel-image doesn't stretch all the way right , you'll need to add `width: 100%;` to this css:

```
/bootstrap.css:5983
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%; /* add this one to fix span issue */
}
```

which, if I remember right, is being compiled from your gem (if Rails). So, you may have to add this shorter version to your bootstrap-and-overrides.css:

```
/bootstrap-and-overrides.css
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 100%; /* add this one to fix span issue */
}
```

**And another thing**
I know you said you're not too up on media queries, but you have crazy top margins below 767px when the spans collapse.

I would encourage you to add this to your `bootstrap-and-overrides.css` file:

```
@media (max-width) {
  .affordable, .valuelist {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

Which will clean up the blank spaces on the page nicely.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I had tried the margin-top as my first attempt to fix it, but that seemed to cause some strange unexplainable problems.  The fix I ended up using was wrapping the .affordable and .valuelist divs inside another div, and then used a media query to add a padding-top at min-width: 737px.  That seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Huh. That worked well for me in Chrome. Go ahead and post your own solution as your answer and accept it. If I provided any assistance, you can always up vote my answer.